# Node JS Iteration problem

Tags: javascript, node.js

у меня проблемы с итераций в Node
JS, первая итерация  проходит нормально а с фторой проблемы

```
await page.waitFor(2000);
const Elements = await page.$$('.wcicon-edit');
await page.waitFor(1000);
const All = [];
for (const handle of Elements)
{
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    // await handle.click();
    await page.waitFor(2000);

    let Information = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let Names =[];
        let Apps= [];
        let RoleName = document.getElementById("Name").value;

        var UserNamesList = document.querySelectorAll("[class='tree-connection-item']");
        for(var ui = 0; ui < UserNamesList.length;ui++ )
        {
            Names.push(document.getElementsByClassName("tree-connection-item")[ui].innerText);
        }

        var SoftNamesList = document.querySelectorAll("[class='rule-label-text']");
        for (var i=0;i<SoftNamesList.length;i++) 
        {
            Apps.push(document.getElementsByClassName("rule-label-text")[i].innerText);
        }

        return { Names, Apps, RoleName };
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предлагаете догадываться, где тут 28 строка, где 30, и что такое `page`?

Comment: видимо, на второй итерации нет требуемого элемента `document.getElementById("Name")`

Comment: @Yaant по скриншоту консоли видно что это page это вкладка в браузере из puppeteer. Но конечно сложно понять что там происходит.

Comment: @EugenePavlyuk мне, например, не видно, хотя бы потому, что я понятия не имею, что такое puppeteer :)